# If $x \geq y>x/2$ then is it true that $x \pmod y < x/2$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I'm not sure how to prove this statement, which I believe is true:

given $x,y \in Z$ such that $x \geq y > \frac {x}{2}$ then $x$ (mod $y$) < $\frac {x}{2}.$

**Edit:**

Would this be an acceptable sketch of the proof?

Suppose that $x \geq y \geq \frac{x}{2};$ consider the bounds where $y = x$ or $y = \frac{x}{2}$. 
In the case in which $x=y,$ then $x$ (mod $y$) = $x$ (mod $x) = 0$.
On the other hand, if $y = \frac{x}{2},$ then $x$ (mod $y$) = $x$ (mod $\frac {x}{2}) = \frac {x}{2}$.
Therefore, $0 \leq x$ (mod $y$) < $\frac {x}{2}$.

Comment: How can $x$ be greater than $x/2$?

Comment: corrected title my apologies

Comment: Your title implies that $x > \frac{x}{2}$.

Comment: x is greater than x/2 for $x \geq 1$

Comment: I  am a moron... Unbelievable.

Comment: I corrected to include the case for $x = 0$. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: For clarity's sake - "$x \pmod y$" refers to the remainder when dividing $x$ by $y$?

Comment: Yes, I uploaded a sketch of an argument for it

Comment: In fact, $x > x/2$ for $x > 0$

Answer (score 2):

This is true.  Suppose that $0\leq \frac{x}{2} < y \leq x$.  Long divide $x$ by $y$ by the Division Algorithm to write $x=yq+r$ where $0 \leq r <y$.  Here, $r$ is your $x \bmod y$.  We claim that $r < \frac{x}{2}$.

Suppose not, so that $r \geq \frac{x}{2}$.  Then $x=yq+r \geq yq+\frac{x}{2}$.  Subtracting $\frac{x}{2}$ from each side gives $\frac{x}{2} \geq yq$.  But $y >\frac{x}{2}$ so this gives $\frac{x}{2} > \frac{x}{2}q$ so $q < 1$.  Hence $q=0$ and $x=r < y \leq x$, a contradiction.

Comment: There may be a faster, less convoluted way to get there, but it's late and I've had 2 beers and 0 coffees.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the title is yes.
Assuming $x > 0$, $x \ge y > x/2 \implies 1≤x/y<2$, so the remainder when $x$ is divided by $y$ is $x−y$ and also $x \ge y > x/2 \implies 0 \le x-y < x/2$.